# Breakpoint exception occurs on run in simulator and device

Tags: ios, xcode, exception

I am experiencing an exception at runtime in my appdelegate. It happens when I try to instantiate viewcontrollers in 2 places in the app, even though I instantiate viewcontrollers in many places with no problem. Also, when I comment out the lines where the exceptions occur, the exception just appears a few lines of code later.

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why this solution works but it appears to have solved the issue. When I remove customFonts from the sourcecode of my xib and storyboard files, the exceptions no longer occur.